# Echo results of mysql query with php

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I have this query

```
$people = "SELECT name FROM people";
$people = mysql_query($people) or die(mysql_error());
$row_people = mysql_fetch_assoc($people);
$totalRows_people = mysql_num_rows($people);
```

I can echo the results within a unordered list using a while loop like this

```
<ul>

<?php {do { ?>

    <li><?php echo $row_people['name'];?></li> 

<?php } while ($row_people = mysql_fetch_assoc($people));}?>

</ul>
```

But I can't used this as my html does not allow it.

```
<ul>
    <li class="first">
        <a href="?name=kate">Kate</a>
    <li>
    <li class="second">
        <a href="?name=john"><img src="john.jpg" />John</a>
    <li>
    <li class="third">
        <a href="?name=max"><span>Max</span></a>
    <li>
</ul>
```

My question is how can echo the name that was retrieved from the database into the appropriate place within this html?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You seem to be missing the `<?php ?>` tags in your code. However, are you saying that you want to output markup like what is in the block of markup? Meaning, you're asking how to adjust it to suit this markup?

Comment: This code: `<?php echo $row_people['name'] ?>` is a XSS security hole. Always escape all output that you echo to html using the function htmlentities(), like so: `<?php echo htmlentities($row_people['name']); ?>`

Comment: I have added the missing php tags. I apologise if my question is confusing. But I want to do is quite simple. Right now I have place holder names in the html like Kate, John and Max. I want to replace these with the names retrieved from the query. So Kate would be replace by the first result, John by the second, Max by the third.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$people = "SELECT name FROM people";
$people = mysql_query($people) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($people) > 0){
?>
    <ul>
    <?php
        while ($row_people = mysql_fetch_assoc($people)){ 
    ?>
            <li><?php echo htmlentities($row_people['name']);?></li> 
    <?php
        }      
    ?>
    </ul>

<?php
}

?>
```

Comment: If am not mistaken this looks like my example above, which I said I could not use as my html would not work with it.

Comment: what's your file extension .html or .php if file extension is .php then its gonna work otherwise you can't use php syntax in .html file. All php syntax would be treated as character

Comment: @jamjam - In all fairness to this answer, your question is not very clear as to what the result is and what the problem is.

Comment: File extension is not the issue. This works but it produces the same result as my while loop above. I cannot use it as it wraps everything a generic li tag. I want to retain the html structure whilst populating names retrieved from the database.

Comment: @VikasNaranje - The OP wants to adjust the output of the `while` loop to match the markup example in the question.

Comment: The problem i see in your html is in each your <a> tag, child of <a> tag is different like in your first <a> tag, child element is a text in second it's <img> and last <a> tag it's <span>. It's means you want  to preserve this type of html structure or something else you want.

Comment: Don't forget to escape anything that you output to html to prevent XSS.

Comment: @VikasNaranje - When you want to comment to someone specifically in the comments below an answer, use `@[username]` to do so. Such as: `@jamjam`. See my first comment for an example.

Comment: Your previous comment to @jamjam I don't think the OP saw, is what I'm saying (or at least wasn't notified).

Comment: @jamjam The problem i see in your html is in each your <a> tag, child of <a> tag is different like in your first <a> tag, child element is a text in second it's <img> and last <a> tag it's <span>. It's means you want to preserve this type of html structure or something else you want

Comment: sorry homie but there is no easy way to do so 
you will have to code more than what you think

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to create a renderer for each "type" of user (assuming you have a type property on the user rows) or based on their attributes. For example, let's say you're going to have to filter based on the attributes:

```
<?php

function render_simple($person) {
    return '<a href="?' . $person['name'] . '">' . $person['name'] . '</a>';
}

function render_with_image($person) {
    return '<a href="?' . $person['name'] . '"><img src="' . $person['image'] . '.jpg"/>' . $person['name'] . '</a>';
}

function render_special($person) {
    return '<a href="?' . $person['name'] . '"><span>' . $person['name'] . '</span></a>';
}

function render_person($person) {
    if ($person['image']) {
        return render_with_image($person);
    }
    if ($person['special']) {
        return render_special($person);
    }
    return render_simple($person);
}

$i = 0;
while ($row_people = mysql_fetch_assoc($people)){ ?>
    <li class="index<?php echo ++$i; ?>">
        <?php echo render_person($person); ?>
    </li>
<?php
}      
?>
```

This should work, with the exception that instead of class names first, second, etc, you'll now have index1, index2, etc.